# Android ANT+: What is a PCC?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, antplus

I've been doing a bunch of ANT+ development for Android.  The documentation and class names refer to "PCC" all over.  Any idea what PCC stands for?  https://www.thisisant.com/APIassets/Android_ANT_plus_plugins_API/com/dsi/ant/plugins/antplus/pccbase/AntPluginPcc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of thisisant.com's Android ANT+ implementation PCC informally stands for Plugin Communicator Class.  I heard from someone who spoke to someone who has worked on the code and this is the answer he gave, though he mentioned its not an official/formal definition.  In reality in this context there really isn't an official definition for Pcc.

Answer (score 0):

It stands for **Parity Check Code**

Comment: That sounds like when PCC is used in a different context, but thank you.